# Refreshing Page With Php

Tags: php

I'm working on a php code where I'm echoing out form values and a file onto the page. I have that working fine but I want to implement a start over button when pressed will display the page again without the echoes. Any suggestions or better ways to do this?

```
<html>
 <head>

 </head>
 <body>
<div class="page">
    <h1>File Loader</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <label>Name:</label><input type="text" name="name"></br>

        <label>Date:</label><input type="text" name="date"></br>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        <input type="button" name="startOver" value="Start Over" onclick="phpfile.php"></br>
    </form>
</div>

<?php
if ($_POST['submit']) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];

    echo "Name: $name</br></br>";
    echo "Date: $date</br>";

    $file_handle = fopen("file.csv", "r");


        while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

            $fields_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 2024);

            $f = $fields_of_text;
            $format = "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s";
            echo "<br>" . sprintf($format, $f[0], $f[1], $f[2], $f[3], $f[4], $f[5], $f[6], $f[7], $f[8], $f[9], $f[10]);

            echo "<br>";

            echo "<br>";
            echo "<br>";
        }

        fclose($file_handle);


 } else {
    header("Location: phpfile.php");
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you saying this code does not work?

Comment: I can't figure out how to get the start over button to reload the page url again.

Comment: for php you would use `header("Location: ` but you seem to want a js solution?

Comment: I tried to set up an if else statement where if post didn't equal submit it would reload by using header("Location: in the else statement but I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: ok then you dont want a button but another submit

Comment: @user320522 see my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use query string/post params.

You can use $_GET like below or you can use a hidden input and change that to 1 or 2 with the onclick and javascript if you need to use post.

```
 </head>
 <body>
<div class="page">
    <h1>File Loader</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <label>Name:</label><input type="text" name="name"></br>

        <label>Date:</label><input type="text" name="date"></br>


        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="window.location.href='phpfile.php?SubmitType=1';">
        <input type="button" value="Start Over" onclick="window.location.href='phpfile.php?SubmitType=2';">

        </br>
    </form>
</div>

<?php
if ($_GET['SubmitType'] == '1') {



    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];

    echo "Name: $name</br></br>";
    echo "Date: $date</br>";

    $file_handle = fopen("file.csv", "r");


        while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

            $fields_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 2024);

            $f = $fields_of_text;
            $format = "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s";
            echo "<br>" . sprintf($format, $f[0], $f[1], $f[2], $f[3], $f[4], $f[5], $f[6], $f[7], $f[8], $f[9], $f[10]);

            echo "<br>";

            echo "<br>";
            echo "<br>";
        }

        fclose($file_handle);


     } 
     else {
        header("Location: phpfile.php");
        exit();
     }
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```